# Object [object Object] has no method 'menu'

Tags: jquery-ui

This is my entire head:

```
<head>
    <title>Experimentation</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylingExp.css">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js">
</script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.7/full/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

I've been wrestling with making a JQuery-ui.menu for far too long! When I attempt to do it like this:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $( "#listtest" ).menu();
    });
</script>

<ul id="listtest">
    <li>Item #1</li>
    <li>
        Item #2
        <ul>
            <li>Item #2.2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Item #3</li>
</ul>
```

I get this:
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'menu'. Can someone tell me why?

Comment: <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
   $( "#listtest" ).menu();
  });
 </script>
This line of code is now the very last element in the body tag. Is that what you meant? It has no effect :(

Comment: Where did you get the plugin? Might be that `menu` is just not in the plugin?

Comment: Then I think it's a configuration problem. Are the js assets loaded in the right sequence? Which one's needed to load first? Check the corresponding docs.

Comment: There is a demo:   $(function() {
    $( "#menu" ).menu();
  });
that works just fine after loading jquery and jquery UI libraries :S

Comment: I don't understand Hoffmann? I load the jquery library first, then jquery-ui. Then I make the script to transform my list into a menu. No other js assets required or utilized, as i see it?

Answer (score -2):

Are you sure that the jQuery and jQuery-ui libraries are being loaded correctly?
you could check this concern with google chromes dev tools in the network tab.

and i suggest you move your JS loading part to the end of the page, not in the `head` section